# Using variables from link in template - AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to use variables defined in link in template? I have the code:

```
return { scope: { x: '=x' }, 
         template: '<div>my X variable: x</div>', 
         link: { 
           var self = this; self.x = JSON.parse(scope.x) 
         } 
       }
```

Like at the example above,I need to use parsed x variable, which is just modified scope x variable.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no need of this line**,

`var self = this; self.x = JSON.parse(scope.x)` Since you are assiging the scope value again,

just use **interpolation**,

`template: '<div>my X variable: {{x}}</div>',`

```
return {
   scope: { x: '=x' },
  template: '<div>my X variable: {{x}}</div>',
  link: {
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not assigning the same value again. I'm assigning parsed to JSON data. And I need this parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Just use double brackets on your html template {{x}} to access scope variable in your html templates.

Comment: but I don't want to access SCOPE variable, just variable from LINK

Comment: Just add a scope within your link function, then it will work the same. Or use ng-controller with self and it will work too.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `{{x}}` in your template, Like below:

```
template: '<div>my X variable: {{x}}</div>'
```

Use following link function and then try to access your variable in template:

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
  scope.y = "y variable";
}
```

and following template:

`<div>Y: {{y}}</div>`

Comment: but I don't want to access SCOPE variable, just variable from LINK

Comment: @AdamJakś You mean a new variable inside the link and then access it in template or something else ?

Comment: Yes, that's what i thinking about.

Comment: @AdamJakś I have updated my answer, Please try this and see if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, scope is not assignable.